# unable to install IO::Pty package for perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

while installation of IO::Pty package at windows vista getting below error:
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/lib/perl5/5.8/msys/CORE/perl.h:925:27: fatal error: netinet/in.h : No such file or directory please suggest me solution

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cygwin instead of mingw, as the [`README`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TODDR/IO-Tty-1.10/README) file suggests:

> Supported systems include Linux, Solaris, AIX, OSF, *BSD, IRIX, HP-UX
>   and Darwin.
>
> **Windows is supported only under the Cygwin environment, see
>   http://www.cygwin.com/.**
>
> Sorry, ActiveState Perl on Windows is NOT supported, basically 
>   because there are no pseudo-terminals under Windows.